# Getting 'Failed to scan URL. Status code: 400 Bad request' when using VirusTotal API to scan URL

Tags: python

I'm attempting to use the VirusTotal API to scan a URL, but I keep receiving the error message "Failed to scan URL. Status code: 400 Bad request." Here's the code I'm using:
import requests

```
def scan_url(api_key, url):
    vt_api_url = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls"
    headers = {
        "x-apikey": api_key,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
    data = {
        "url": url,
    }
    response = requests.post(vt_api_url, headers=headers, json=data)
    if response.status_code == 201:
        return response.json()
    else:
        print(f"Failed to scan URL. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        if response.status_code == 400:
            print("Bad request. Check if the URL is properly formatted.")
        elif response.status_code == 403:
            print("Forbidden. Check if your API key is valid and has proper permissions.")
        elif response.status_code == 429:
            print("Rate limit exceeded. Too many requests. Try again later.")
        else:
            print("Unknown error occurred.")
        return None

api_key = "***"
url = "https://www.blogger.com"
result = scan_url(api_key, url)
if result:
    print(result)
```

I've double-checked the URL, and it seems to be properly formatted. However, I'm still encountering this error. Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue? Thank you.

Comment: 400 is a general error that just means you made some mistake.  Maybe you sent a wrong header, or wrong data, or maybe the api key was wrong.  Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.virustotal.com/reference/scan-url), it looks like the request is not supposed to use json.  Why are you using json?

Comment: try to use curl or some rest services tool like postman / insomnia where you can replicate  the api request and see why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not providing a valid API Key which is required (more details on their API documentation: https://docs.virustotal.com/reference/scan-url)

You will also see that if you print the response text `print(response.text)` under the else statement.

By the way, you can get a public API key just by signing up to VirusTotal Community. More about that on this link https://docs.virustotal.com/reference/getting-started

Comment: if you mean my api_key "***" then I changed it due to privacy